# tapestry properties file + injection , implement support for parameter[n]

Tags: java, code-injection, tapestry

I am rather new to tapestry. In tapestry project here such case

parameters are in **X.properties** file, e.g.

```
SomeService.urlDoOnething=http://etc/etc1
SomeService.urlDoOtherthing=http://etc/etc2
```

in **1.java**

```
@Inject
@Value("SomeService.urlDoOnething")
private String SomeServiceurlDoOnething
@Inject
@Value("SomeService.urlDoOtherthing")
private String SomeServiceurlDoOtherthing
```

in **2.java**

```
request = new ClientRequest(SomeServiceurlDoOnething); ....
```

I must implement SomeService[N].url*thing parameters.
User can choose service from combobox (thinking also how to implement combobox thing elegantly).

As I don't know tapestry much and searching docs/google hasn't been very helpful yet.. maybe I can find good advice here - how can I do this in the most elegant / least coding way?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your question completely, can you further explain this part:

> I must implement SomeService[N].url*thing paremeters. User can choose
>   service from combobox (thinking also how to implement combobox thing
>   elegantly).

what I think i do understand is that you have two phases to your problem:

1. how to ingest a properties file
2. how to access the key/value pairs via injection

to solve **1**:

Add the following to your Module (AppModule.java):

```
public void contributeSymbolSource(OrderedConfiguration<SymbolProvider> providers)
{
    providers.add("ExtraConfiguration", new ClasspathResourceSymbolProvider("extra.properties"), "after:SystemProperties", "before:ApplicationDefaults");
}
```

to solve **2**:

In your Page.java, use `@Symbol` instead of `@Value`:

```
@Inject
@Symbol("SomeService.urlDoOnething")
private String urlDoOnething;
```

Comment: properties file would look something like this.

What I would like to do is to load whole SomeService*.* properties into
some table SomeServices[][] .

SomeService1.urlDoOnething=http://11etc/etc1
SomeService1.urlDoOtherthing=http://11etc/etc2

SomeService2.urlDoOnething=http://22etc/etc1
SomeService2.urlDoOtherthing=http://22etc/etc2

SomeServiceN.urlDoOnething=http://NNetc/etc1
SomeServiceN.urlDoOtherthing=http://NNetc/etc2